# Can no longer generate a DLL moving from Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, windows-xp, mingw

I have some C++ code that, on 32 bit Windows XP, generates a DLL. Porting the project under 64 bit Windows 7, I only get the object files, but no DLL and no error messages.

Apart from the Windows version, the tools used in the two systems are roughly the same:

- MinGW
- gcc 3.4.5 on WinXP, gcc 4.6.1 on Win7
- CodeBlocks 10.05

The makefiles and CodeBlocks' config files are the same.

The warnings I get from gcc on Windows XP are not relevant.
These are the warnings I get from gcc on Windows 7, which do not seem to be relevant, either:

```
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute for 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread' must follow the 'class' keyword|
S:\sw\WRXLL\CExcelSpreadsheet.cpp||In member function 'void CExcelSpreadSheet::SetCellFormat()':|
S:\sw\WRXLL\CExcelSpreadsheet.cpp|641|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'CHAR*'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute for 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread' must follow the 'class' keyword|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute for 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread' must follow the 'class' keyword|
S:\sw\WRXLL\FunctionImpl.cpp||In function 'void RetrieveAllRuns()':|
S:\sw\WRXLL\FunctionImpl.cpp|135|warning: unused variable 'BrakesHeaderFound'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute for 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread' must follow the 'class' keyword|
S:\sw\WRXLL\FunctionDef.h|137|warning: missing braces around initializer for 'char [256]'|
S:\sw\WRXLL\MenuDef.h|58|warning: missing braces around initializer for 'char [255]'|
S:\sw\WRXLL\MenuDef.h|91|warning: missing braces around initializer for 'char [255]'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute ignored in declaration of 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread'|
S:\include\CThread.h|58|warning: attribute for 'class DFS::Infrastructure::CThread' must follow the 'class' keyword|
S:\sw\WRXLL\main.cpp||In function 'xloper* xlAddInManagerInfo(xloper*)':|
S:\sw\WRXLL\main.cpp|247|warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 16 warnings ===|
```

What surprises me is that I am given no error at all about the fact that no DLL could have been generated (I did look for it on the whole hard disk, in case it was placed somewhere else).

It is like if the linker was not called at all...

Creating a separate, dummy project on Windows7 I got the DLL. So it is not the tools fault.

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: I think we'll need to see some code here.

Comment: Did you try to use the same MinGW / gcc version on both systems?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I am afraid it is quite a big project, not easy to post here.

Comment: do you have write permission to write the DLL in the target folder?

Comment: @OrenS.: Shouldn't the DLL be placed in the project directory by default? And shouldn't I get an error message if the build system tries to put it where I do not have write access?

Comment: @DocBrown: unfortunately I must keep those versions. Do you know if it is possible to install two different versions of MinGW/gcc on the same computer?

Comment: From the MinGW installtion HOWTO: "The whole C:\MinGW subtree is fully relocatable which means there can be several different versions of the MinGW toolchain installed in parallel,"

Comment: @DocBrown: I will immediately try. Thank you!